# Logstash not writing to Elasticsearch with Shield

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-plugin, logstash-configuration, elasticsearch-shield

I have been trying to make logstash write to elasticseach with shield without success.

My setup was working nromally before installing the shield plugin to elasticsearch.
I've followed [this guide from elastic.co](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/logstash.html) and created a new user for the `logstash user role` using:

```
esusers useradd logstashadmin -r logstash
```

I've also updated the `logstash output configuration` and added the `protocol`, `user`, and `password` as suggested in the guide.

After restarting both logstash and elasticsearch, I am still not receiving anything on elasticsearch coming from logstash. Did I miss anything?

Here is my setup:

```
$ esusers roles logstashadmin                         
logstashadmin  : logstash

$ cat shield/roles.yml
...
# The required role for logstash users
logstash:
  cluster: indices:admin/template/get, indices:admin/template/put
  indices:
    'logstash-*': indices:data/write/bulk, indices:data/write/delete, indices:data/write/update, indices:data/read/search, indices:data/read/scroll, create_index
...


$ cat logstash/output.conf

output {
  elasticsearch {
    protocol => "http"
    cluster => "logstash"
    user => "logstashadmin"
    password => "logstashadmin123"
  }
}
```

Note: I've also installed the `transport` plugin in logstash and tried it instead of `protocol => "http"` with the same negative results.

Let me know if you need more info. Thank you

#### Edit 1:

Elastic search logs:

```
[2015-06-12 05:59:16,952][INFO ][node                     ] [Silver Sable] stopping ...
[2015-06-12 05:59:17,087][INFO ][shield.license           ] [Silver Sable] DISABLING LICENSE FOR [shield]
[2015-06-12 05:59:17,088][INFO ][node                     ] [Silver Sable] stopped
[2015-06-12 05:59:17,088][INFO ][node                     ] [Silver Sable] closing ...
[2015-06-12 05:59:17,104][INFO ][node                     ] [Silver Sable] closed
[2015-06-12 05:59:20,479][INFO ][node                     ] [Lionheart] version[1.4.5], pid[28662], build[2aaf797/2015-04-27T08:06:06Z]
[2015-06-12 05:59:20,480][INFO ][node                     ] [Lionheart] initializing ...
[2015-06-12 05:59:20,586][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Lionheart] loaded [license, shield], sites []
[2015-06-12 05:59:21,301][INFO ][transport                ] [Lionheart] Using [org.elasticsearch.shield.transport.ShieldServerTransportService] as transport service, overridden by [shield]
[2015-06-12 05:59:21,301][INFO ][transport                ] [Lionheart] Using [org.elasticsearch.shield.transport.netty.ShieldNettyTransport] as transport, overridden by [shield]
[2015-06-12 05:59:21,301][INFO ][http                     ] [Lionheart] Using [org.elasticsearch.shield.transport.netty.ShieldNettyHttpServerTransport] as http transport, overridden by [shield]
[2015-06-12 05:59:27,166][INFO ][node                     ] [Lionheart] initialized
[2015-06-12 05:59:27,166][INFO ][node                     ] [Lionheart] starting ...
[2015-06-12 05:59:28,148][INFO ][shield.transport         ] [Lionheart] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/10.1.0.25:9300]}
[2015-06-12 05:59:28,209][INFO ][discovery                ] [Lionheart] logstash/uuDCpM6hTKKvLNd2oFGYpA
[2015-06-12 05:59:32,032][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Lionheart] new_master [Lionheart][uuDCpM6hTKKvLNd2oFGYpA][0ba2a1c6e1de][inet[/10.1.0.25:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2015-06-12 05:59:32,119][INFO ][http                     ] [Lionheart] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/10.1.0.25:9200]}
[2015-06-12 05:59:32,119][INFO ][node                     ] [Lionheart] started
[2015-06-12 05:59:33,007][INFO ][shield.license           ] [Lionheart] enabling license for [shield]
[2015-06-12 05:59:33,013][INFO ][license.plugin.core      ] [Lionheart] license for [shield] - valid
[2015-06-12 05:59:33,028][ERROR][shield.license           ] [Lionheart] 
#
# Shield license will expire on [Saturday, July 11, 2015]. Cluster health, cluster stats and indices stats operations are
# blocked on Shield license expiration. All data operations (read and write) continue to work. If you
# have a new license, please update it. Otherwise, please reach out to your support contact.
#
[2015-06-12 05:59:33,162][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Lionheart] recovered [2] indices into cluster_state
```

Logstash logs: (this part gets duplicated many times)

```
NotImplementedError: block device detection unsupported or native support failed to load
       blockdev? at org/jruby/RubyFileTest.java:67
         device? at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/filewatch-0.6.2/lib/filewatch/helper.rb:67
  _sincedb_write at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/filewatch-0.6.2/lib/filewatch/tail.rb:230
   sincedb_write at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/filewatch-0.6.2/lib/filewatch/tail.rb:203
        teardown at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-file-0.1.10/lib/logstash/inputs/file.rb:151
     inputworker at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:203
     synchronize at org/jruby/ext/thread/Mutex.java:149
     inputworker at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:203
     start_input at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:171
```

Comment: Any logs/trace of log stash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a non shield related issue. Check this issue:
https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/3127

Just like the post mentions, executing the following did the trick for me:

```
ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so
```

Comment: Wow thanks that solved it for me. That is one weird bug. I don't know why the same exact setup was working for me before installing shield. That is why I thought it to be the source of the problem. Thanks!!